# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

This is my code. It should send message to the channel when user join the server.

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print('+') #this works perfectly
    ch = client.get_channel(84319995256905728)
    await ch.send(f"{member.name} has joined")
```

But error was occur. This is the output:

```py
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/client.py", line 351, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 30, in on_member_join
    await ch.send(f"{member.name} has joined")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

I had enabled server member intents in dev portal.

```py
intents = nextcord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='=',intents=intents)
```

May I know how to fix it?

Comment: The call to `client.get_channel()` is failing and returning `None`. So `ch` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: I think you should be able to get the joined channel from the guild property of the member object. Refer to this [example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/1952060e1af7224ed7b67bc957e47247f6b50493/examples/new_member.py#L11-L14).

Comment: R U sure that a channel with such ID (84319995256905728) exists?

Comment: @Alex yes the channel is not exist. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @BoarGules yes the channel is not exist. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your inputs. Above issue has been taken care. Issue was the channel with id `84319995256905728` did not exist, and I fixed it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your bot has the ability to send a message in that channel, otherwise it will say it can't send it, if it does make sure that channel Id exists.
for an example:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  channel = client.get_channel(900247143351210004)
    await channel.send(f"{member.mention} has arrived!, check out our announcments channel for server and bot announcements!")
```

Comment: If the code works make sure to checkmark it so people know that they answered the question @Iaeden Tai